# /var/debconf/config.dat is locked

Tags: apt, dpkg, update-manager, debconf

**Question / Problem**

apt-get upgrade fails with

```
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Any ideas of what else can I try to solve or identify the problem?

**Background**

This is on Ubuntu 19.10.

Today I received a pop up error window while using the gui Software Updater. Sorry, I forget exactly what it said. Looking in /var/log/apt I see that an error actually occurred yesterday

```
Start-Date: 2020-02-18  06:24:48
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.686'
Upgrade: dmidecode:amd64 (3.2-2, 3.2-2ubuntu0.1), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.26.3-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.19.10.1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.26.3-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.19.10.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.26.3-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.19.10.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.26.3-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.19.10.1)
Remove: linux-headers-5.0.0-40:amd64 (5.0.0-40.44), linux-image-5.0.0-40-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-40.44), linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-40-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-40.44), linux-headers-5.0.0-40-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-40.44), linux-modules-5.0.0-40-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-40.44)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2020-02-18  06:24:50
```

but that a subsequent ?run of the gui? completed without error

```
Start-Date: 2020-02-18  06:25:48
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.686'
Upgrade: dmidecode:amd64 (3.2-2, 3.2-2ubuntu0.1), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.26.3-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.19.10.1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.26.3-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.19.10.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.26.3-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.19.10.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.26.3-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, 2.26.4-0ubuntu0.19.10.1)
End-Date: 2020-02-18  06:25:50
```

The log entry from today's first run of the gui Software Updater is

```
Start-Date: 2020-02-19  06:17:37
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.1055'
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.6, 242-7ubuntu3.7), udev:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.6, 242-7ubuntu3.7), libudev1:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.6, 242-7ubuntu3.7), systemd-sysv:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.6, 242-7ubuntu3.7), libpam-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.6, 242-7ubuntu3.7), systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.6, 242-7ubuntu3.7), libnss-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.6, 242-7ubuntu3.7)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2020-02-19  06:17:57
```

apt-get upgrade fails with "/var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked"

```
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.7) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam-systemd:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$
```

**Investigations / What I've tried**

/var/cache/debconf/config.dat does not seem to be in use

```
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$ fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$ lsof | grep config.dat
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$
```

Removing the lock file (as per [this Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1495612)) didn't seem to change anything.

```
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo rm lock
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.7) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam-systemd:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$
```

Recalling the problem originated with the gui Software Updater, I tried also removing lock-frontend

```
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo rm lock lock-frontend 
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.7) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam-systemd:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$
```

Then I tried removing the lock and lock-frontend files and using the gui Software-Updater, which resulted in a "The software on this compute is up to date" with apperently no info entered in /var/log/apt/history.log. However apt-get upgrade still results in the same problem.

```
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.7) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam-systemd:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$
```

Trying apt -f doesn't help

```
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo rm lock lock-frontend 
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-get -f upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.7) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam-systemd:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
me@9380:/var/lib/dpkg$
```

Comment: Its a day later and a restart seems to have helped cleared this problem out. Software Updater prompted for an update, which subsequently failed as above, I restarted and ran apt-get update/upgrade successfully. The thing that's odd is that I had tried restarting a few times when I originally encountered the problem. So as of now, the best answer I have to my original question ("...what else can I try to solve or identify the problem?") is to wait some time and try again. That's lame though. Any better ideas?